# DC.js Disable SelectMenu

Tags: dc.js, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I have two selectMenus, I want the selectMenu 2 to be disabled until the user interacts with selectMenu 1.

How to disable a dc.js - selectMenu in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the first render, I would disable the second selectMenu using the [`disabled` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select). You have to wait until it's rendered because before then, the `select` element doesn't exist.

Then, on the `filtered` event, I would re-enable it.

[Here's a demo with three selectMenus.](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/tuLehpm0/7/)

Relevant code:

```
  dc.renderAll();

  select2.select('select').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  select3.select('select').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

  select1.on('filtered.enable', function() {
    select2.select('select').attr('disabled', null);
  });
  select2.on('filtered.enable', function() {
    select3.select('select').attr('disabled', null);
  });
```

(Is that enough different uses of the word "select"?)

Comment: hahaha... It worked! I had to do some relevant changes to the reset buttons as well.

Comment: a follow up question. Is it possible to keep the filtering of select menus in a single direction? I mean selectMenu2 can get filtered by selectMenu1, but selectMenu1 should not get modified, when I select something in selectMenu2. Is that possible?

Comment: It's possible but I think there might be some weird edge cases. The basic idea is to copy the group data into a fake group and swap it in. But like I say, you will probably run into weird cases like when do you swap it in, when do you need to swap it back out, etc. Feel free to ask another question if you want help thinking it through; I'm on vacation for another week.